# GitHub API - get total number of reviews by an author on a repository

Tags: github, github-api

I know that I can get the number of PRs opened by a given user with

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:pr+repo:<owner>/<repo>+author:<username>+is:open
```

But what about the number of PRs *reviewed* by a given user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be available in the v3 (REST) API, but I found `totalPullRequestReviewContributions` in the v4 (GraphQL) API.

```
{
  user(login: "nickmccurdy") {
    contributionsCollection {
      totalPullRequestReviewContributions
    }
  }
}
```

After making the GraphQL query, you'll get this JSON as a result. Only the number for `totalPullRequestReviewContributions` should change.

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "contributionsCollection": {
        "totalPullRequestReviewContributions": 80
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since this is using the v4 (GraphQL) API, you can test it out from the GraphiQL API Explorer: https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

Comment: Great, thanks! Now I just need to filter on the repository

Comment: Found it: {
  user(login: <user name>) {
    contributionsCollection {
      pullRequestReviewContributionsByRepository {
        contributions {
          totalCount
        }
        repository {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}